# Python: global name 'foobar' is not defined

Tags: python, scope, global

Can someone explain why the following code produces an error "global name 'foobar' is not defined" on line 12 (the print statement)? I thought I understood scope in Python, but this is giving me fits.

```
def main():
  # initialize
  global foobar
  foobar = Foo()

class Foo():
  def __init__(self):
    self.bar = Bar()

class Bar():
  def __init__(self):
    print foobar

#Call main() when script is executed
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: It seems like you're maybe expecting `global foobar` to "declare" a variable and initialize it to a default value? Variables don't work that way in Python. All `global` means is "When you see an assignment to this variable, assign it as a global instead of a local". There's still no variable until such an assignment happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time `Foo()` is called, `foobar` is not yet defined (it won't be until `Foo()` returns and its return value is assigned to `foobar`. However, `foobar` is accessed *by* the call to `Foo()`, indirectly vi the call to `Bar.__init__()`. Thus, at the time `print foobar` in `Bar.__init__` is executed, the global `foobar` is not yet defined. If you set the value of `foobar` prior to the call to `main`, you'll see that value printed before the `Foo` object is assigned. Try the following

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    foobar = 3
    foobar = Foo()  # This will output "3"
    print foobar    # This will print something like <__main__.Foo object at 0x.....>
```

As abarnert  points out, `global foobar` doesn't create the variable `foobar`; it just ensures that the variable created by the following assignment is created at the global scope, not as a local variable in `main`.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`global foobar` needs to reference `foobar` that already exists.

e.g.

```
foobar = 0

def foo ():
    global foobar
    print (foobar) #python 3
```